# How do I typehint away this reflection warning?

Tags: reflection, clojure

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
(proxy [javax.swing.JPanel] []
  (paintComponent [#^java.awt.Graphics g]
    (proxy-super paintComponent g)
    (.fillRect g 100 100 10 10)))
```

"Reflection warning, call to paintComponent can't be resolved"

Comment: If you ever figure this out I'd be interested to know.  I looked into the implementation of `proxy-super` and it looks like it's always going to reflect if you call a protected method, but I'm uncertain I'm reading it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because proxy-super use implicit `this`.

```
(let [^javax.swing.JPanel this this]
  (proxy-super paintComponent g))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the warning is for the line

```
(proxy-super paintComponent g)
```

Does the parent class of javax.swing.JPanel have a paintComponent method?

Removing that line works for me.